# How do EOD and EOF work together in Terraform?

Tags: bash, here-document

This is the script from my terraform course

```
      provisioner "local-exec" {
          command = <<EOD
    cat <<EOF > aws_hosts 
    [dev] 
    ${aws_instance.dev.public_ip} 
    [dev:vars] 
    s3code=${aws_s3_bucket.code.bucket} 
    EOF
    EOD
}
```

I have already seen EOF before.It is very usefull when working with multi-string line in bash. What is EOD for?

Comment: identifiers after `<<` are just arbitrary names for heredoc de-limiters. There is no special meaning behind `EOD` or `EOF` in general. You could have very well just had `blahblah` to start/stop the delimit the heredoc

Comment: Why do we have EOD? Can I get rid of it?

Comment: https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/11279#issuecomment-294413401 -> seems the outer set of `<<EOD`/`EOD` is for multiline string literals in Terraform.